# Evento de click

Tags: javascript

Não estou conseguindo realizar o evento de click.

Quando clico no menu de hamburguer, não acontece nada. O que pode ser?

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

header{
    background-color:#776E6E;
    height: 105px;
    
}

.container{
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    
    
}

.logo{
    width: 119px;
}

.cabecalho{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    
}

.menu{
    width: 660px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    position: absolute;
    
    margin: 400px;
}

.link-menu-barras{
    display: none;
    width: 30px;
}



.banner{
    background-image: url(imagem/banner.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height: 535px;
    left: 0px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .container{
        width: 85%; /*a largura vai ficar com 85% para layouts que possuir  */
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

    .link-menu-barras{
        display: inline-block; /*Se o layout for menor ou igual a 768px, (vai aparecer o menu de barras) */
    }

    .menu{
       display: none; /* se o layout for menor ou igual a 768px, (o menu com os links será escondido) */
       
    }

}


@media  screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    header {
        background-color: darkslateblue; 
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ptbr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">


    <script>
        let menu = document.getElementById("menu"); /*buscando o ID*/
        console.log("executou")
        function mostrarMenu() {
            if (menu.style.display == "none") {
                menu.style.display = "flex"
            } else{
                menu.style.display = "none"
            }
        }
    </script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="container cabecalho" >
            <a href=""><img src="imagem/logo.svg" class="logo" alt=""> </a>  
                <nav id="menu" class="menu">
                    <a href="">Mais vendidos</a>
                    <a href="">Eletronicos</a>
                    <a href="">Informática</a>
                    <a href="">Vídeo-Games</a>
                    <a href="">Smartphones</a>
                </nav>
                <!--Evento de clique: quando o elemento for clicado, será chamado a função (mostrarMenu) -->
                <a href="" class="link-menu-barras" onclick="mostrarMenu()" ><img src="imagem/bars-solid.svg" alt="icone do menu de barras"></a>
        </div>
        </header>
        <section class="banner">
        </section>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Tire o script do `<head>` e passe para final do `<body>`. Quando faz isso `let menu = document.getElementById("menu");` no `<head>` a página ainda não foi carregada e `menu` é `undefined`.

Comment: Boa noite pessoal. Obrigado pelas informações. ao seguir o passo a passo que foi sugerido, mesmo assim não obtive êxito. Alguma outra alternativa?

Answer (score -2):

### Dei uma olhada aqui e você pode tentar algumas coisas.

- Ao invez de executar a função no onClick passe a referencia dela
- coloque a tag a por volta do componente de menu ou coloque o evento de onClick no Container.
- tire o `display: none` da tag a.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).